# How programatically we can transfer file form android mobile 2.0(API level 8) to windows PC?

Tags: android, usb, file-transfer

our requirement is for API LEVEL 8 (android 2.0). In our application we have requirement of transfering file from my android phone to PC via USB.
Here i would create user interface which can show me the file structure of windows system where i can copy the file or reverse also will do. that is transfering file from windows pc to mobile but programmatically via USB. i dont know whether i am going in right direction or not can anybody help me on that. and suggest me the right way to define the problem so i can achieve some right solution.
Thank you in advance...

Comment: I think you should put some more details in your question.

Comment: i will state my problem very simply 'I want to transfer file from my android SD card to windows c: drive (but it should be programatically)' this is fine now i think. thank you Khan

Comment: I got what you put here and from that you seems to be in the right direction. But my question was about the details of your implementation.

Comment: my implementation would be android application with user interface which will show the windows directory and allow user to give path to copy the files form android phone to selected directory on PC. thank you khan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instructions on how to use the android USB api, please checkout this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. my question is it that i am going in right direction

Comment: i got the answer but it is for API level 12 or higher. i want for API level 8

Answer (score 0):

This must have been a bit easier using sockets over wi-fi but by using USB its almost impossible. The USB host api available on android docs is for usb devices which is useless in this case. So the only option available might be to establish device to host computer communication through usb by using adb. Refer this link for help([Connecting android to pc using USB](http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/connecting-android-to-the-pc-over-usb/)).